# Is it okay/possible to initialise an array with new objects in php

Tags: php, arrays, object

What I want to attempt:

```
class thing{
  public $name = "default";
  public $stats = [1,2];
}

$myArray = (object)array(new thing,'internalArray'=>[(object)[],new thing]) //un-named objects in a complex array/object
```

There are a great number of ways to 'put' objects in arrays. The question I ask is to where the boundaries and limits are in putting objects in new arrays. This particular question may not lead to the most effective answer for many readers but it will at least clear up why(for me) a new object is/isn't good practice in an initialized array.

In searching through the PHP Manual, Stack Overflow, and ... W3Schools - I've found little to nothing that helps with this specific case, depending on how you perceive the lack of examples. No info could just mean that this is "a dumb idea" and one should never mind themselves with it.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to initialise an array with objects in it.

Whether that's "okay" probably depends on whose judgement you prefer, and/or which goal you try to achieve. I'd personally optimise for readability first; from that perspective "initialising an array with objects in it" could certainly be a valid choice.

In terms of readability, however, I must say I find the example rather confusing. I see an array that has a mix of numeric and some associative indices, which gets converted to a standard object. If readability is the goal, there are probably better ways to express the intent of the code.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Strata.
The example was to show the variance in what I'm attempting. My own work is wanting for some better readability, and this practice does help.